# Openshift will have docker UCP ?

Tags: docker, openshift

hi i am new to openshfit can some one please help me on below

1. docker Universal Control Plane  will be availabe in openshift as well  or instead of UCP we are using openshift ?
2. how i can manage my new application deployed in openshift  like ssl certs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker UCP is a tool for managing Docker Swarm clusters. OpenShift is an entirely different product based on Kubernetes for container management and scheduling.

OpenShift applications ate exposed publicly via routes, https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/routes.html. Routes is where you will install you SSL certificates for a specific hostname.

Comment: UCP has support for Kubernetes in the latest beta.